# Java: What should I learn to be able to access databases and studd like that?

Tags: java

I'm a fairly new programmer right now I'm learning to program console based programs. I more into the databases and security stuff and I'm wondering what should I learn?

Comment: What do you mean by "what other types of Java is there" ? You're seeking for another programming language which only allow you to do console development such as COBOL ? That would be an horrible choice. You can develop program that stick to the console using Java.

Comment: He's referring to other types of Java programs, e.g. GUI applications and such

Comment: It's not a question likely to be constructive

Comment: I downvoted because I could not understand your question. There seems to be missing words.

Comment: Yes you can... This is easy stuff. You can program near everything in Java.

Comment: Yes, Java is a fairly popular language and can be used to access databases, program web applications, and run on embedded devices

Comment: If you are new to software development, I am going to make leap and guess you are new to databases too.  If you want to work with databases you will need a basic understand of the types of database you wish to work with, perhaps starting with RDBMS and SQL, as you will need to understand the structure of the data in the database and how to manipulate and query the database for the data.

Comment: @Gavin That is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found two resources very helpful in getting me up and running with databases and security. For security, please use only salted hashes, as these are the most difficult to break. See [this](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) article for more information.

For connecting to databases, see [this](http://mrbool.com/how-to-connect-with-mysql-database-using-java/25440) article.

Comment: Please excuse the lack of examples, as I am on mobile as I post this

Answer (score 2):

Java is a general purpose programming language, pretty much any sort of application can be written using it.

Like all languages Java is better suited to some types of programs than others, but its all dependent on the effort you wish to put in, and on their being a JVM for the target environment.

Answer (score 1):

Java targets the JVM environment, and it is preferred for many different types of application development for its stability, flexibility, cross-platform compatibility, and vast number of libraries.

Tools like MySQL and Hadoop are commonly used with Java in database infrastructures and server-side scripting. It has great potential for security-related uses. The Android development platform is also based on Java.

However, as mentioned by others, Java is considered a general-purpose language. The bests uses for it are dependent on your own efforts and interests.